# Change iMessage account on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, messages, apple-id

My partner gave me his iPad mini but I cannot use iMessage as it is linked to his account and I cannot change accounts. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings → Messages → Send & Receive, tap the Apple ID and choose Sign Out, then sign in with the Apple ID you wish to use.

Comment: I tried this and it just comes up with "an error occurred during activation"

Comment: if "Find my iPad" is not turned on you should be able to wipe it (Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings. If it is turned on you will need your friend to enter his password to turn it off.